# DRools: no-loop true attribute not working with update() method inference

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, drools, redhat

I have a simple DRools package with a single rule whose DRL source is the following:

```
package com.rules.standard.isolatesFlags.GRUPPI_FAMIGLIE;

import org.package.path.ResultIsolate;

global org.apache.log4j.Logger logger;

function void finalizeIsolate(ResultIsolate isolate, Logger logger) {
    /* implementation */
}

function void setIsolateCSIFlag(ResultIsolate isolate, Integer csiAlarm, Logger logger) {
    /* implementation */
}

rule "ConfirmEsccolWasplab" 
    dialect "mvel"
    salience 10
    enabled true
    no-loop true

    when
      $a : ResultIsolate( deviceId == "WASPLAB_core" , microId == "h_W_ESCO" )
      $b : ViewPlateResult( plateStatus >= 60 , plateCode == "h_CCA" ) from $a.isolatePlates

    then
      finalizeIsolate($a,logger);
      setIsolateCSIFlag($a,new Integer(-1),logger);
      update($a);
end
```

Then, in my Java EJB I execute rules like the following:

```
kSession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
kSession.addEventListener(ruleListener);
            
logger.debug("Injecting global variabiles isTest and logger and EJB MicroRulesUtils into StatefulKnowledgeSession");
kSession.setGlobal("logger", org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(MicroBusinessIsolateFlagsImpl.class));
                
kSession.insert(resultIsolate);
kSession.fireAllRules((int)MicroBusinessIsolateFlags.MAX_FIREABLE_RULES); //1000
```

`ruleListener` is a vlass which implements `AgendaEventListener` interface and in implementation of method `beforeActivationFired` I count how many rules are activated and fired for each single fact.
In fact, in my EJB, after firing rules, I check:

```
if(ruleListener.getNumberOfFiredRules() >= MAX_FIREABLE_RULES) {
    logger.info("Isolate flags rules fired more than ",MicroBusinessIsolateFlags.MAX_FIREABLE_RULES, " times. Check configuration to prevent inference loops from occurring.");
    logger.info(ruleListener.getRulesActivationsLog()); //print fired rules and how many times
}
```

So, it always happens that this warning is showed. How is it possible? As I said, I have a single package with a single rule and with `no-loop true` attribute I woudl expect that the rules itsself is no more activated as consequence of its RHS. But it is. Is that a bug?
Also after adding other rules of packages which are not activated (the conditions of the contained rules are not matched) then I always get thet rule logged as fired 1000 times (a loop).
I am using DRools 5.0.1 and I am not allowed to upgrade it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. It's how the feature works.

Calling `update` is functionally equivalent to calling 'fireRules'. It's as if we exited the current 'fire rules' flow, and then reran all the rules with new data. Since it's a new run, there's no previous executions, so `no-loop` doesn't apply.

This is in comparison to `insert` (for example). When you call `insert` in the RHS of a rule, the engine merely re-evaluates subsequent rules in the *current run*. In this case, 'no-loop' *does* apply, because we're still in the same run, and the previous executions remain.

`no-loop` is intended to keep the same rule from firing more than once in a single execution of the rules. It's not intended to keep the rule from firing across multiple executions.

To make your rule not fire on update, you need to modify your left hand side to exclude the condition that is set on the right hand side. Since you've omitted your definition of the `setIsolateCSIFlag` function, I'll make up a simple example instead:

```
rule "EXAMPLE"
no-loop
when
  Address( $locality: locality )
  $purchase: Purchase( sum > 0, tax == null )
then
  $purchase.calcualteTaxForLocality($locality); // sets 'tax' to some value
  update( $purchase );
end
```

Since the Purchase instance now has a non-null `tax` value, the rule doesn't trigger again after the `update`. In your situation, you should update your conditionals (LHS) to not fire based on whatever the `setIsolateCSIFlag` method actually does. Or, alternatively, don't call `update`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the docs at one point explained the differences between `insert`, `modify`, `update` in terms of this, but I can't find it in the latest. Possibly one of the older versions of the docs still has that explanation in it.

Comment: Thank you for your precious explanation. I had studied inference as much as possibile before introducing it in our product and I think I missed those differences. So, should I wrap the whole RHS of the rule into `modify { }`, then I would get the expected behaviour with `no-loop` attribute? Because, in our case, users perform rules composition by our self-made Java Frontend in Swing, where `update($a)` is added as last instruction of the RHS of the rule if a silly checkbox `Inference` is flagged. Could this be a solution?

Comment: Moreover, I had already thought of your solution: my `finalizeIsolate` function updates to 60 the state of the ResultIsolate object, so in the condition of the rule it would be required to have also `isolateStatus < 60` in the pattern matching selector of $a, but it is completely up to the configurator user himself. Often our rules are created in a hurry and many things are missed by our delivery.

Comment: Re the rules created in a hurry -- at the company i previously worked for where we had millions of these rules (I personally was responsible for 1.4 million rules, which in retrospect is insane), we actually unit tested our rules and reported out coverage metrics on that.

Comment: Re `modify` you'll need to look at the semantics of that particular action and see if it calls `update` under the hood or if it acts more like `insert` and modifies the existing flow in-place without restarting.